# What query to obtain the following on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view

Users

```
+--------+--------------+----------+--------------+
| userID | userUsername | userName | userLastName |
+--------+--------------+----------+--------------+
|      6 | richard      | Ricardo  | Vega         |
|     10 | jason        | Jason    | Bourne       |
+--------+--------------+----------+--------------+
```

Restocks

```
+-----------+-------------+--------+--------+-----------------+
| restockID | restockDate | itemID | userID | restockQuantity |
+-----------+-------------+--------+--------+-----------------+
|         1 | 2012-02-29  |      1 |      6 |              48 |
|         2 | 2012-02-29  |      1 |     10 |             100 |
|         3 | 2012-02-29  |      2 |     10 |              50 |
|         4 | 2012-02-29  |      2 |      6 |             100 |
|         5 | 2012-02-29  |      2 |      6 |             200 |
|         6 | 2012-02-29  |      2 |     10 |            2000 |
|         7 | 2012-02-29  |      1 |     10 |            2000 |
+-----------+-------------+--------+--------+-----------------+
```

Items

```
+--------+--------------------+
| itemID | itemName           |
+--------+--------------------+
|      1 | Coca Cola (lata)   |
|      2 | Cerveza Sol (lata) |
+--------+--------------------+
```

Ok guys, i have supplied some sample data as requested. I need to get this table:

```
+--------+--------------------+---------------+-------------+----------+--------------+--------------+
| itemID | itemName           | itemExistence | restockDate | userName | userLastName | userUsername |
+--------+--------------------+---------------+-------------+----------+--------------+--------------+
|      2 | Cerveza Sol (lata) |          2350 | 2012-02-29  | Jason    | Bourne       | jason        |
|      1 | Coca Cola (lata)   |          2148 | 2012-02-29  | Ricardo  | Vega         | richard      |
+--------+--------------------+---------------+-------------+----------+--------------+--------------+
```

But, i need restockDate to be THE LATEST ONE for each itemName. In the example, it shows the first restock and not the latest one. I just need to show what's the existence for the item and **when was restocked for last time**, not first time.

If my tables are not good or so, please suggest a new schema.

***I know maybe this is a lot so i will tip 5 USD (Paypal) to the one how can help me with this. Promise.***

Comment: Probably if you could provide some sample data (as tables) we could understand what exactly you're looking for. This is an [example question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475177)

Comment: Do you mean you should a distinct itemName for each user,ie group by userid or username and itemId

Comment: Your *"WHAT I NEED"* part needs more explanation. An item is related to many users and restockDates. So, if you have one row per item, which of the many users (and restockDates) should be in the output?

Comment: What is `itemExistence`?

Comment: itemExistence = old stock + new stock. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in comments, many restocks can be performed on the same day so it is not possible to compare dates in this case. Two options are presented here: Use the incremental PK from `restocks` table or restructure the table. For the first case, this is the solution:

```
select i.itemID, i.itemName, i.itemExistence, r.restockDate, u.userName,
  u.userLastName, u.userUsername
from items i
left join (
    select r1.restockDate, r1.itemID, r1.userID from restocks r1
    left join restocks r2
    on r1.itemId = r2.itemId and r1.restockId < r2.restockId
    where r2.restockDate is null
) as r on i.itemID = r.itemID
inner join users u on r.userID = u.userID
```

For the second case, the restructre would imply changing the date field to a unique datetime that would uniquely identify a record. That is the best solution, however, it does require to also update any previous data present in the table. That means, to update all the records that have the same date for a single product restock and set different date times to them.

The lazy one (like me), would go for the first option :) Let me know if you have any doubt about this.

Comment: Tried that. Thanks. I've just supplied sample data as requested. I hope this help clarifyng things.

Comment: My Mostacho friend, ive tried that and it brings a lot of results. I just need itemName to be Distinct, i mean, for example, just one itemName called Coca-Cola with his last restock. Same for Cerveza, only one Cerveza and his last restock. Same for any Item. I hope you can help me. Those queries are getting scary :P

Comment: LOL, here we go again :P. My result table shows the following: itemID is the unique ID for each itemName. restockDate i wanted to be the LAST time itemName was restocked. A item can be restocked N times and it records a date. I just need to show the LAST RESTOCK DATE and WHO (userName, userLastName, userUsername) did it. What i need in other words, is just to list items and show who updated for the last time. But i only need to list each item once. For example: the CocaCola item has many restocks, but i just need the last one and who did it.

Comment: More info: Jason, Ricardo or John Doe can restock any item. For example, i can restock everyone of them, then, you use the system and Mostacho updates all of them. When i run the query, it must show all the items and your name as "responsible" because you were the last person to restock them. No need to show my stocks, only yours because they are the latest ones. Hope this clarify things. Thanks a lot for you invaluable time and help my friend.

Comment: If i have 2 restock of the same product in the same day, i want to show the lastest one. Maybe i can change to DATETIME the restockDate or we can use the restockID so that way, we can tell what's the new one based on restockID (autoincrement). I can't answer with your data which ones i want to keep because it has to involve as i said the restockID or some field that let us choose the latests restocks.

Comment: I knew there was something missing :) I've just updated my answer

Comment: Mosty Mustacho: YOU ARE THE MAN !!!! It is working just freaking fine. Altought the query is kinda scary. I think i will need to get a book about advanced MySQL :P. Do you have a Paypal account? i said there was a tip for anyone that can help me :)

Comment: It's done my friend. Thanks for your patience and invaluable help.

Answer (score 1):

first get the distinct from items table and then use it to join others

```
SELECT items.*, restocks.restockDate, users.userName, users.userLastName, users.userUsername
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT items.itemID, items.itemName, items.itemExistence FROM items) AS items 
LEFT JOIN restocks on items.itemID = restocks.itemID
LEFT JOIN users on restocks.userID = users.userID
GROUP BY items.itemName
```

Not Tested

Comment: It works too! However, as i said to my friend in another answer, how do you get restockDate ordered by desc? In other words, i need the latest restockDate for each item.

Comment: try changing the join for restocks to  

LEFT JOIN (SELECT itemID, restockDate FROM restocks ORDER BY restocksDate DESC) AS restocks ON items.itemID = restocks.itemID

also the above answer suggestion would be best to implement, change date field format to datetime

Comment: cant edit the above anymore, but i think this version will work


LEFT JOIN (SELECT itemID, MAX(restockDate) FROM restocks GROUP BY itemID ORDER BY restocksDate DESC) AS restocks ON items.itemID = restocks.itemID

it would get the max from date grouped by itemId for the join statement

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED

```
select items.itemID, items.itemName, items.itemExistence, restocks.restockDate, users.userName, users.userLastName, users.userUsername
from items 
inner join restocks on items.itemID = restocks.itemID
inner join users on restocks.userID = users.userID
GROUP BY items.itemName
```

Comment: Thanks, that's one of the combos ive tried before. It doesn't work because the itemName must be distinct for me to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
select    
items.itemID, items.itemName, items.itemExistence, 

(select A.restockDate from restocks A where A.itemId = items.itemID limit 0, 1),
(select B.userID from restocks B where B.itemId = items.itemID limit 0, 1),

users.userName, users.userLastName, users.userUsername

from items 

left join users on B.userID = users.userID
```

Please try this.

Comment: It works! Is there a way to ORDER BY restockDate DESC ?? each row show the restock date, i need the last one of distinct items. For example, item Coca-Cola can be restocked N times. I just need to get the most recent date. Please?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what `itemExistence` is, so I'm hoping it's a column in the `Items` table.

Here's an easy way to do it with a self-join:

```
SELECT i.itemID, i.itemName, i.itemExistence, r1.restockDate,
  u.userName, u.userLastName, u.userUsername
FROM Items i
JOIN Restocks r1
  ON r1.itemID = i.itemID
JOIN Users u
  ON u.userID = r1.userID
LEFT JOIN Restocks r2
  ON r2.itemID = i.itemID
  AND r2.restockDate > r1.restockDate
WHERE r2.itemID IS NULL
```

The `LEFT JOIN` with the `WHERE` clause ensures that we only pull the row with the latest `restockDate`.

The advantage of this approach is that it avoids subqueries, which often negate the use of indexes.

You can get duplicate records for a particular item if it was restocked more than once on the same date.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried that and it didn't work. I just need to show unique itemName and the restockDate for that item. itemExistence is simple math: old stock (for example 6) + new stock (30) = itemExistence (36).

Comment: I don't see `old stock` or `new stock` in the information you provided. MySQL says, "didn't work"? I guess we're stuck then.

Comment: old stock and new stock is a php function. I look for the current stock and then add the new stock and that operation is what itemExistence is. MySQL didn't say didn't work. The result is what im not looking for :P.